# Read out selected text on HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I want a feature in my site so that the user has the option of selecting a text on the page and pressing a button to listen to what is selected. Is this achievable?

Comment: how to achieve the same?

Comment: I'd look into Bing's translation API (i'd recommend google's, but they're shutting it down soon). And then just translate from english to english. I believe they give you the ability to play the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive used the google translate service in the past:

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=*YOUR TEXT HERE*

which will produce an mp3 file. You will then either need some kind of plug in to play that mp3 file back. I use a flash movie with the following actionscript 3 code:

```
var googleTranslateIntoSpeech:URLRequest=new URLRequest('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q='+text);
contentAudio=new Sound(googleTranslateIntoSpeech);
contentAudioChannel=new SoundChannel();
contentAudioChannel=contentAudio.play();
```

However as maxedison has mentioned the google translate service is probably going to be shut down soon. I would imagine the Bing translation service is comparable and the solution would be very similar.